# Kryo registration of LabeledPoint class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, kryo

I am trying to run a very simple scala class in spark with Kryo registration. This class just loads data from a file into an `RDD[LabeledPoint]`.

The code (inspired from the one in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint



object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    sc.getConf.registerKryoClasses(classOf[ org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint ])
    sc.getConf.registerKryoClasses(classOf[ org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] ])

    // Load data
    val rawData = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_tree_data.csv")
    val data = rawData.map { line =>
      val parts = line.split(',').map(_.toDouble)
      LabeledPoint(parts(0), Vectors.dense(parts.tail))
    }

    sc.stop()
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

What I understand i that, as I have set `spark.kryo.registrationRequired = true`, all utilized classes must be registered, so that I have registered `RDD[LabeledPoint]` and `LabeledPoint`.

**The problem**

I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint[]
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint[].class);
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:442)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:472)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:565)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As I understand it, it means that the class `LabeledPoint[]` is not registered, whereas I have registered the class `LabeledPoint`.

Furthermore, the code proposed in the error to register the class (`kryo.register(org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint[].class);`) does not work.

- What is the difference between the two classes?
- How can I register this class?

Comment: I have stumbled into a similar problem with the `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` yesterday, I still haven't solve it but I know that the code proposed is in `java` that's why it won't work. You ought trying `kryo.register(org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint.getClass)` instead. This didn't work for me neither but at least it's syntactically correct. Any thoughts on that @zero323 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @eliasah who contributed a lot to this answer by pointing out that the proposed solution (`kryo.register(org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint[].class);`) is in `Java` and not in Scala.

Hence, what `LabeledPoint[]` means in Scala is `Array[LabeledPoint]`.

I solved my problem by registering the `Array[LabeledPoint]` class, i.e. adding in my code:

```
sc.getConf.registerKryoClasses(classOf[ Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] ])
```

Comment: I'll try this today, if it works for me, I owe you a drink ! ;-)